# how are these functions called if I didn't call them?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I'm new to QT.
How are these functions automatically called if I didn't call them?

Maybe somewhere inside the parent class there are connections that somehow connect them and launch them?

I know there will be a default constructor here, but how are these functions called, if the default constructor is empty

```
class CustomItem : public QGraphicsItem{
```

public:

```
QRectF boundingRect() const override{
    return QRectF(0, 0, 80, 80);
}

void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override{
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);

    painter->fillRect(boundingRect(),Qt::red);
}
```

}item;

Comment: *How are these functions automatically called if I didn't call them?* -- Use the debugger, put a breakpoint in one of those functions, and when the breakpoint is hit, look at the call stack.  This not only pertains to your situation, that's the way to figure out how any function was invoked.

Comment: as a general rule of thumb with UI code, one doesn't call "paint" directly, but a part of the screen is invalidated, and when the UI thread next has a chance to update the screen, it'll call paint.  The idea is that if the underlying data is updating faster than the UI can redraw the screen, you'll get multiple updates done in a single repaint.  If you look carefully at the arguments, you'll find that one of them has the coords that should be re-painted - and that may well be a part of the widget rather than all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public methods can be called by anyone who has a pointer or reference to objects of your class.

Presumably objects of this type are added to a `QGraphicsScene`, which among other things will call `boundingRect` to determine how much space your `CustomItem` occupies, and `paint` when it needs to draw the part of the scene with that item.